# What does gave it into the fire mean?

Tags: british-english

It's Ariana grande one last time.

Does it mean that she just went in and passed away.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please note that song lyrics, like poetry, can be interpreted in many different ways, and opinion-based answers are [not well-suited to our format](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I encourage you to [take the site tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better understanding of how we operate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for an interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: You also shouldn't ask questions that require people to search online to find some context.  The question should be answerable as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means she gave in to desire/temptation, and cheated on her lover - who is now her ex-lover.

> And I know, and I know, and I know
>   She gives you everything  But, 
>   boy, I couldn't give it to you
>   And I know, and I know, and I know 
>   That you got everything
>   But I got nothing here without you.